# Show that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}^+,k \ge 2$, it is $\left \lfloor k \sin \frac{2}{k}\right \rfloor =1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification

> Show that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}^+,k \ge 2$, it is $\left \lfloor k \sin \frac{2}{k}\right \rfloor =1$.

I tried this: for any $u \ge 0$, it is $\sin u \le u$ and $\sin u=u \iff u=0$, so since $k \in \mathbb{R}^+,k \ge 2$ it is $\frac{2}{k} >0$ and so it is $\sin\frac{2}{k}<\frac{2}{k}$. This implies that $k \sin \frac{2}{k}<2$.

Since for any $k \in \mathbb{R}^+,k \ge 2$ it is $0<\frac{2}{k} \le 1$, it is $\sin \frac{2}{k}>0$ and so $k \sin \frac{2}{k}>0$.

Hence for any $k \in \mathbb{R}^+,k \ge 2$ it is $0<k \sin \frac{2}{k}<2$; since by definition it is $[t]=\max\{j \in \mathbb{Z} \ s.t. \ j \le t\}$, from $0<k \sin \frac{2}{k}<2$ it follows that $\left \lfloor k \sin \frac{2}{k}\right \rfloor =1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: But why can't it be $0$? You need to have a reason for that. Note that $$\lfloor t \rfloor =\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } 0 \leq t <1\\ 1 & \text{ if } 1 \leq t <2\end{cases}$$

Comment: @AnuragA Thanks for the help. You are right, I made a silly mistake. I corrected it like this: since the sine is concave on $(0,\pi/2)$, it follows that $\sin \frac{2}{k}>\frac{4}{\pi k}$ and so $k \sin \frac{2}{k} > \frac{4}{\pi}>1$; now I can conclude that the result is $1$. Now it should work, do you agree?

Comment: Yeah that was the missing thing.